# Как сохранить MovieClip средствами Flash+AS3+PHP

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, php

Например у меня есть MovieClip, там можно рисовать. Далее мне нужно сохранить нарисованное в изображение *.jpg или* .bmp неважно.
Как это сделать?
Не понятно как можно сделать из мувика изображение. 
Я новичок в AS3, а классов огромное количество.
Если как нибудь сделать из мувика изображение, можно передать на сервер классом FileReference, а там php-скриптом уже можно сохранить.

Answer (score 1):

создание битмапы на основе визуального объекта, мувика, спрайта, графики, не суть

```
var b:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, true, 0x0);
b.draw(s);
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(b);
```

сохранение на сервер

```
var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (sketch_mc.width, sketch_mc.height);
jpgSource.draw(sketch_mc);

var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("jpg_encoder_download.php?name=sketch.jpg");
jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");
```

активно использовался гугл, на основе запросов

> adobe actionscript 3.0 save bitmap
>
> adobe actionscript 3.0 bitmap from
> sprite

во втором примере используется либа - http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/